# Connect Windows version of R to Hadoop

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs

I am trying to connect R to a Hadoop cluster using R.  The cluster has HDFS, Map Reduce, Hive, Pig and Sqoop installed on it.

R will be running on in the Windows environment.  I know that rhdfs, rhadoop and rmr exist for Linuix, but I can't find anything on Windows.

Does anyone know of a library to use?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Revolution Analytrics](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/) is trying to make a name for themselves in this space. They have a couple of nice packages (some of which are open-source and/or free for non-commercial use) which allow you to interact with Hadoop from R in a Windows environment fluidly.

Comment: Author of rmr here, we don't test on Windows yet. We are kind of waiting for better Hadoop support there, which doesn't depend on us but we know there are people working on it. Best bet right now is the VM approach, which is running linux on top of Windows and everything else (R and hadoop) in linux. That may be close enough for your goals or not.

Comment: Is it possible for the current version of R-3.0.1 in windows?